# Passing a Toolbar component to DataGridPro is causing rerender

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the `DataGridPro` component from MaterialUI 5.10.

I have a toolbar component like so:

```
function TableToolbar({ title }: MyProps) {

  return (
    <ToolbarWrapper>
      <GridToolbarContainer>
        <GridToolbarQuickFilter
          debounceMs={200}
        />
        <GridToolbarFilterButton />
        <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
        <GridToolbarExport
          csvOptions={{
            title,
            allColumns: true,
            utf8WithBom: true
          }}
          size="large"
        />
      </GridToolbarContainer>
    </ToolbarWrapper>
  );
}
```

This is passed into the DataGridPro like so (removed some props for brevity).

```
<DataGridPro
  components={{
    Toolbar: (props) => <TableToolbar title={props.title} />,
    Cell: (props) => <TableCell {...props} />
  }}
/>
```

My problem is that passing in `props` to the `TableToolbar` causes the component to rerender and lose focus. I know that this is the problem as if I remove the requirement for this prop, it works as expected.

Unfortunately, it seems to be a hard requirement that the name of the table being exported is put part of the exported file's name.

Is there a way that I can pass in this `title` prop without it causing a rerender?

Comment: please try using `slots` and `slotProps` props instead of `components` and `componentProps`

Comment: I couldn't use slots as we're on an older version for the moment. However, thanks to your answer I did find about the existence of `componentProps` and that has solved my issue!